# How to make this render more realistic (Cell Material)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders, photorealism

I have a project that I am working on for science class. I am trying to make a cell and am having a lot of trouble with getting the cells to look realistic.

I am also farely new to working on shaders without a tutorial.

This is the cell so far:

[image]

However I don't like the look of it so far. It kind of looks like a bad modelled primary school example of a cell - which is not what I am trying to achieve.

What are some things I should change about this render?

And what should I do to take that primary school 5 minutes modelled class example look out of it?

I am trying to make it look like this:

[image]
Thanks you :)

Comment: Hello, do you have some reference image to show how the cell should look like?

Comment: @moonboots yes i do, i will put it in the post

Comment: I meant some inspiration 3D picture to see how other 3D artists have made it?

Comment: is it supposed to look like this: https://zupimages.net/up/22/09/pwyy.jpg or like this:https://zupimages.net/up/22/09/fguf.jpg

Comment: @moonboots Yes, I am trying to make it look somewhat like the first one - thank you.

Comment: First off, lighting is very important here. I'd suggest using several area lights for a softer effects. After that, most materials seem to be very simple diffuse or transmissive shaders, you can add a little bit of SSS on some of them if you feel like it fits.

Comment: @Throndronis thank you, i will try that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to come close to the first picture I link:

[image]

It's a mix of several things, like good lighting and good material. In your material you need to use a bit of *Subsurface Scattering* in order to have something a bit translucent (don't forget to change the *Subsurface Radius* values that are in RGB). Also give it a bit of noise to get color spots and 3D relief. At last, tweak the *Roughness* and *Specular* in order to get the correct reflectivity:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to J. Flutto and Moonboots’s answers, I would also suggest giving the liquid a bit of refractive transparency as well with a mixed-in Glass shader with very low to no roughness to make the liquid look more watery (as I recall intercellular fuel is).

If you’re using Cycles, you should be set.  If you’re using Eevee, though, you’ll need to make sure to set screen space reflections and to also set the liquid material to refractive in the Material Options panel.  While you’re there, make sure the liquid and all objects visible through it do not have “Alpha Blend” transparency set.  If these conditions aren’t met, then the glass shader won’t look right.

Answer (score 1):

Better lighting goes a long way. Maybe try an HDRi? And maybe also change the roughness of those materials and add a bit of Subsurface Scattering.